# Add a unique timestamp to a text using Selenium and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, strftime

Quick question which I thought I'd find a simple answer to but so far, no luck.

I'm creating automation to go through sign up forms and for this I ideally need to send some unique text. I was thinking of something like name+timestamp (as do-able on Ghost Inspector).

Currently I'm okay just writing a quick unique name each time in my code (using send.keys('')), just looking to see if there's a way to cut this small chore out really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a *unique* **timestamp** to a text you can use *Python's* [**`strftime()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) method from [**`time`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from time import gmtime, strftime

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.google.com")
  driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("James Stott{}".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())))
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: name_timestamp_strftime]

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to generate random Strings which you can send it to `sendKeys("")` command.

```
import string
import random
def random_string(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for m in range(length))

print random_string(10)
print random_string(5)
```

If you want to use UUID :

```
import uuid

id = uuid.uuid1()  
print (id.hex)  // for hex representation 
print (id.int)
```

If you want to use timestamp, then you can use this code :

```
import datetime
print('Date now: %s' % datetime.datetime.now())
```

here is the reference link :  [datetime python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)